# Exception while accessing JSON from HTTPS with p12 certificate

Tags: java, json, ssl, https

Using Java, I have to read a JSON string from an URL with a p12 certificate. I have imported the certificate to jre1.8.0_51\lib\security\cacerts successfully using

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeystore cacerts -srckeystore ..\certificate\cert1.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass mypass -alias cert1
```

I can also see the JSON string in Chrome. However, when I try to read it from Java, I get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am using this code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://myurl");
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("certificate/cert1.p12");
ks.load(fis, "mypass".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ks);

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(ks, "mypass".toCharArray());

SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslCtx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSF = sslCtx.getSocketFactory();

URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
if(conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSF);
}
conn.connect();
```

However, this code produces the obove exception. I am on Windows 10. What am I missing? Thanks!